# jQuery Validator Does Not Validate Input File Type

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-validation-engine

I've written a upload form and I want users to be able to upload only images.
I've decided to use jQuery validator in order to make sure that users cannot send an empty form an can only upload images. So far, users indeed can't send an empty form, but they can upload and file they would like to , even if it's not an image.
Here's the code of `jsFunc.js`  which aim to handle this problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#upload-image').validate({
    errorElement : "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(".upload-error");
    },
    rules: {
        pic: {
            required: true,
            accept: "image/*"
        }
    }
});
});
```

Here are the files included in the page that included the upload form :

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jsFunc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

What is wrong with the code above? I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the problem.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9kYYH/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny , thanks , I've also checked it using jsfiddle and that's why it seems strange. I've not edited the post and included the files i'm importing, maybe something it wrong / missing ?

Comment: The order of imports is wrong `jquery.validate.js` first then `additional-methods.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of script file imports is wrong, `jquery.validate.js` first then `additional-methods.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sys/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all , thanks for the answer ! I'd like to know please why there is any importance for the order of file importing ?

Comment: because the additional-methods files uses features included in the validate.js file. so when the `additional-methods` file is executed it expects the validate.js file to be already executed

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to validate by file extension or to accept only images with certain extension you can use like this

```
rules: {
   field: {
     required: true,
     extension: "jpeg|png"
   }
}
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension

Comment: Could you please share jsfiddle for  it?

Comment: Please how would you collect the values of the file field and the text field into another page after validating them

Answer (score 0):

```
rules: {
   field: {
     required: true,
     accept: "jpeg|png"
   }
}
```

Replace extension with accept, it 'll work